# Expressjs - Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, express

I know there are similar questions but they seem to vary a lot in implementation, so it seems there isn't a 'one solution fits all'. I have read all of them but I cannot figure out what is wrong in my case.

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const auth = require('basic-auth');

const app = express();
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

app.get('*.gz', (req, res, next) => {
  res.set('Content-Encoding', 'gzip');
  res.set('Content-Type', 'text/javascript');
  next();
});

app.use(express.static('public'));

// For AWS Fargate to check if service is OK
const helthCheck = async (req, res, next) => {
  const returnError = (message) => {
    if (!res.headersSent) {
      res.status(500);
      res.send(`Error: ${message}`);
    }
    next();
  };
  const returnErrorProductApi = (message, prefix) => returnError(`Product API - ${prefix}: ${message}`);
  const apiUrl = 'https://www.censored-fake-domain.com/graphql';
  const query = `{
    filters
  }`;
  const prefix = 'Filters';
  try {
    await fetch(apiUrl, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({ query }),
    })
      .catch(() => returnErrorProductApi('Bad response.', prefix))
      .then((result) => result.json())
      .catch(() => returnErrorProductApi('Invalid JSON.', prefix))
      .then(() => {
        if (!res.headersSent) {
          res.send(`OK: ${prefix}`);
        }
        next();
      });
  } catch (error) {
    returnErrorProductApi('Bad response.', prefix);
  }
};

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (req.originalUrl === '/favicon.ico') {
    next();
    return;
  }
  if (req.originalUrl.indexOf('/health') !== -1) {
    helthCheck(req, res, next);
    return;
  }

  const credentials = auth(req);
  if (!credentials || credentials.name !== 'censored-username' || credentials.pass !== 'censored-pass') {
    res.status(401);
    res.header('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm="example"');
    res.send('Access denied');
  } else {
    next();
  }
});

// we should allow sub-paths like /lorem also
// but right now we only have 1 route so this is fine
app.get('*', (request, response) => {
  response.sendFile(`${__dirname}/app/index.html`);
});

const listener = app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Your app is listening on port ${listener.address().port}`);
});
```

Everything works fine except commandline node keeps outputting/spamming:

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at SendStream.headersAlreadySent (/lorem/node_modules/send/index.js:390:13)
    at SendStream.send (/lorem/node_modules/send/index.js:617:10)
    at onstat (/lorem/node_modules/send/index.js:729:10)
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:166:5)
```

Comment: Why is `health_check` async? I see that it awaits on the fetch chain, but why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have more than one area where you are doing `res.send(..)`, followed by `next()` which then goes on to a route which could also hit `res.send(...)`.

You have to ensure that any time you invoke `res.send(...)`, it doesn't happen again. The easiest way to do this would be to replace any `res.send(...)` with `return res.send(...)`.

Edit for clarity:

When you call next after `res.send(...)` (event though you return after it) it will always go on to call the next item, which is trying to send a file.

for example, you have

```js
if (req.originalUrl.indexOf('/health') !== -1) {
  helthCheck(req, res, next);
  return;
}
```

which you might think would end the request, but within healthCheck, it calls next, which prompts

```js
app.get('*', (request, response) => {
  response.sendFile(`${__dirname}/app/index.html`);
});
```

to be called, even though healthCheck already sent a response.

Comment: Aha I didn't know `next()` worked like that! I simply changed it to be `if (!res.headersSent) { res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/app/index.html`); }`

Answer (score 1):

you are sending response twice here

```
if (!res.headersSent) {
      res.status(500);
      res.send('Error: ' + message);
    }
```

and here

```
if (!res.headersSent) {
          res.send('OK: ' + prefix);
        }
```

remove one of them and it will works correctly

Comment: How do I send Http status header 500 and the message then? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes 500 is for the header and then I want to set the body https://www.cleantutorials.com/html/format-of-http-request-response-header-and-body-with-example

Comment: `res.status(500).send({ message: "Error " + message});`

Comment: It doesn't help at all, I think you missed the point. `.catch()` is called if there is an error and `then()` is called if there wasn't any error. It can't be both not an error and an error.. and using chaining or not doesn't matter. The Basic Auth below in code doesn't use chaining and it works fine..

Comment: I know that ... what you should do is send the res one time in `then()` and another time in `catch()` but you send the res twice in different places but with the same condition which is `if (!res.headersSent)` that is your problem